# Anyone studying for PMP exam or have passed PMP?

Tags: pmp

Is there anyone here who is studying for PMP exam or someone who has passed the exam already ?

I have two questions for those who have passed:
Q1. Let's say I have read the book and understood the process but didn't memorize anything including Process Groups and Knowledge-Areas mainly Input, T&T and Output process.

Will this help narrow down the situational questions and pass the exam ?

Q2. On the other extreme, I memorized all I/P, O/P and T&T of all Knowledge-Areas. Will this make me a better person to answer situational questions ?

Any clues on how you passed will help.

Those who are studying for PMP exam, or those failed before and trying again:

Q. What is your strategy to pass this time around or pass on first attempt ?

Answer (score 3):

There are no tricks to passing the PMP. You need to know and understand the information to pass it.

Passing the PMP is about understanding PMI's definitions of a project and how to run it. If you do not have a strong knowledge of the PMBoK and haven't memorized the formulas and key things like Process Groups, then you'll likely not pass the test. You could be a 20 year veteran of project management and not pass the test. You need to know the PMI-isms, or how PMI defines things.

I passed through study and memory drills. That and being a project management professional with strong experience.

The only suggestion I can offer you, is to use the computer tutorial time wisely. The exam walks you through a basic how to use a computer and the program tutorial. When I took it, it was about 15 minutes. During this time I instead took one of the provided sheets of paper, the provided pencil and started writing down all the key formulas and memory areas which I had memorized. I'd probably written that piece of paper twenty times before that.

Comment: My testing center provided the pencil and paper AFTER the tutorial, so don't rely on this time.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. Let's say I have read the book and understood the process but
>   didn't memorize anything including Process Groups and Knowledge-Areas
>   mainly Input, T&T and Output process.
>
> Will this help narrow down the situational questions and pass the exam
>   ?

No, neglecting to memorize anything will not help you pass the PMP exam.

> Q2. On the other extreme, I memorized all I/P, O/P and T&T of all
>   Knowledge-Areas. Will this make me a better person to answer
>   situational questions ?

It will put you in a better position to pass the exam but you will not pass with with rote memorization.

> Any clues on how you passed will help.

- Memorize Rita's process chart in the order it's in; understand why it's in that order.
- Find all the free tests you can.
- BrainBok.com also helped, and I paid for that.